6.12 Real-time Linux vs Ubuntu Real-time
Following the news about RT being a part of mainline kernel (link below) beginning of release 6.12 I have a general wonderment about the differences and overall future of Ubuntu specific PREEMPT_RT patch https://ubuntu.com/real-time. On paper those seem to wrap the same solution, is this gonna be a hard drop-in replacement or are there plans to continue the development of Ubuntu specific RT patch alongside?
https://www.zdnet.com/article/20-years-later-real-time-linux-makes-it-to-the-kernel-really/
Best regards!
